# uitableview row render strange behavior

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I want two create 2 sections uitableview 
so I did the following code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@" I entered numberOfSectionsInTableView");
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {          
    if (section = 0 ) {  
        1;   
    }
    else {
        9; 
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSLog(@" I entered cellForRowAtIndexPath");
    NSLog(@"the Caf files count is : %d",[self.CafFileList count] );
    NSLog(@" the txt file %d",[self.TXTFileList count] );
    if (indexPath.section == 0 ) { // Enter here twice , even I say it contain only one row
        NSLog(@"////////////////////////Section 0 %d" , [indexPath row] );  
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }   
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[self.TXTFileList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] ]   ];    
        return cell;    
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row < [self.TXTFileList count]  ){
        NSLog(@"////////////////////////Section 1 %d" , [indexPath row] );
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[self.CafFileList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]   ];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

the problem is that it Enter here twice , even I say it contain only one row

```
if (indexPath.section == 0 ) {
```

any idea how to solve that

Comment: if (section = 0 ) { ? and then 1; :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't return row numbers in `numberOfRowsInSection`, you just enter a number, but return nothing.

Also,

```
    if (section = 0 ) {
```

**sets** `section` to 0, you want to use the `==` operator.

Comment: what do u mean by if (section = 0 ) {

Comment: Your `numberOfRowsInSection:` function does that. The = operator is an assignment operator, you should change it to ==, which is the comparison operator

Answer (score 3):

```
if (section == 0 ) {  
    return 1;   
}
else {
    return 9; 
}
```

Also your code:

```
else if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row < [self.TXTFileList count]  ){
```

You never generate cell for section == 1. seem will crash or wrong reusing cell